# Logarithmic time C# list

Tags: c#, data-structures

Does there exist an implementation for .NET of a list collection such that both insert and lookup are worst-case O(log(n)) operations?  The default [System.Collections.Generic.List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) '[Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx)' method is an O(n) operation.

By a list collection, I mean an array-like expandable data structure.  By 'lookup' I mean access by index.

I suspect this can be done with balanced trees, but would be non-trivial to implement.

Comment: What do you mean with "List" and "lookup"? You mean an array-like expandable structure that can be accessed on O(log(n)) time by index or by "lookup" you mean "search for a value given a value"? (so like a Dictionary/Hashtable)

Comment: Sorry, I mean an array-like expandable structure, and I mean accessed by index.  I'll update.

Comment: Note that with the implementation of `List<T>` of .NET, while the worst case for add to tail is O(n), the "medium" case is still O(1) time complexity. In the end, if you make a calculation, if you add n items, you will have n insert and n copy operations, so 2 * n * O(1) operations, so O(n) complexity.

Comment: Why do you need structure like this? And you want to insert at any position or just at the end?

Comment: @xanatos, the average case for `Insert()` is O(n). That's because it inserts at specified position in the list have to move all items after it.

Comment: @svick I was correcting to "add to tail" :-)

Comment: How about the SortedSet in System.Collections.Generic?

Comment: svick - For the purposes of the question, I wish to be able to Insert at any position, just as with System.Collections.Generic.List

Comment: @CrosbieSmith, but could you explain why do you need that?

Comment: Polity - SortedSet maintains items according to a predefined IComparer, whereas a list maintains items in arbitrary order.  They do slightly different things.

Comment: SortedDictionary and similar aren't a good solution because you can't insert new items. How do you insert an element at index 0? Do you renumber all the other elements? So O(n). (I have deleted my answer for this reason)

Comment: I wonder if this could be done with a variant of a heap data structure.  Basically, each node would know how many children it had and the "key" would be the node's index.  A bit counterintuitive and I am not sure it would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know of a .NET implementation, but a data structure that might work for you is an Indexible Skiplist. It has similar O(lg n) performance like a balanced binary tree but is conceptually more like a linked list.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list

I don't think it would be too hard to write one in C#.

Comment: Thank-you Mr.Lippert.  Given your position I am inclined to take that as a definitive 'no' to my question, unless someone can point me to an actual implementation.  Regarding skipped lists, the Wiki article was a little unclear but they don't seem to guarantee worst-case log(n) performance?  They are interesting though - like a linked-list with 'express' and 'local' lines.

Comment: The problem with implementing a skip list in C# is the huge allocation overhead of the forward pointers array in each node. I wrote a bit about it last year here: http://blog.mischel.com/2010/10/10/c-versus-the-data-structure/  I did finally implement a more memory-efficient version, by allocating  one big array for the forward pointers and having the nodes index into that array. It works, but isn't especially pretty.

Comment: @CrosbieSmith: They have a *probable* sublinear performance, but not a *guaranteed* sublinear worst-case performance. That said, I have not actually implemented a SkipList since my Algorithms and Data Structures class in 1993, so I might be misremembering.

Answer (score 1):

The [C5 TreeSet](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.0/c5doc/types/C5.TreeSet%601.htm) should give you a red/black implementation with those characteristics, including index access.

Comment: This is interesting.  However, according to the description, this collection is sorted.  I take that to mean the order is determined by a pre-provided comparer, whereas a List allows for an arbitrary order determined by the Insert method arguments.  So, interesting as it is, the TreeSet doesn't seem to implement a list.

Comment: Ah, I see now.  You are going to have a hard time finding an off-the-shelf container that provides both insert-order preservation and better-than-linear lookup.  It'd likely have to be a composite container that keeps a sorted copy/index of the list; you could probably roll your own with an array and a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the link though.  It's very nice to have open-source collections code available to learn from.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if there exist in the .net framework, but you can implement [aa tree](http://demakov.com/snippets/aatree.html) insert and search is both O(log n).

Answer (score -1):

There is no possible solution for this if you need to access fields using their index. You can use a SortedList, but then you get O(n), or you can use SortedDictionary, but then you lose the array-like access (by index).

Comment: Why do you think there is no possible solution? Balanced binary tree could certainly do this.

Comment: Yes, it could, but it wouldn't be accessible using index (at least in case the array size is unknown at the beginning).

Comment: It could just update tree nodes appropriately. I know of no existing collection with these properties, but I see no reason why it should be impossible to code one.

Comment: @MZetko, if you remember the size of subtree of each node, you can access by index in O(log n).